# Windows form xmpp Application

Tags: matrix, xmpp

I am trying to make my own XMPP Client, I am using Matrix SDK as XMPP Library. I have set up my own eJabberd server and integrated it with MYSQL. I can successfully connect with clients. I can also successfully Connect within the console Application using Matrix SDK. But When I try to use Windows form Application on_Click event it send request to the server but does not sign in. I can see that in the log.

This is my Connection Class

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionStatus;
     XmppClient xmppClient = new XmppClient();

    public Connection()
    {

        ConnectionStatus = "Connecting";
        xmppClient.Compression = false;
        xmppClient.Hostname = null;
        xmppClient.StartTls = true;
        xmppClient.Status = "Online";
        xmppClient.Password = "123456";
        xmppClient.Username = "xeeshan";
        xmppClient.Hostname = "rabta.cloudapp.net";
        xmppClient.Port.Equals(5222);

        xmppClient.OnLogin += new EventHandler<Matrix.EventArgs>(xmpp_OnLogin);







    }

    private void xmpp_OnLogin(object sender, Matrix.EventArgs e)
    {
        xmppClient.Status = "I'm chatty";
        xmppClient.Show = Matrix.Xmpp.Show.chat;
    }
    public void Open()
    {
        xmppClient.OnLogin += new EventHandler<Matrix.EventArgs>(xmpp_OnLogin);
        try
        {
            xmppClient.Open();
            Thread.Sleep(8000);
        }
        catch
        {
            ConnectionStatus = "Not Connected";
        }
     }
}
}
```

My window Form Application CLick event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       Connection conn = new Connection();
       conn.Open();

    }
```

This is from my ejabberd Server logs. Each time a line is inserted When I click on the button.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2014-07-21 20:32:18 ===
I(<0.430.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.3742>) Accepted connection         {{182,187,194,83},11511} -> {{100,77,176,105},5222}

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-07-21 20:33:37 ===
I(<0.430.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.3744>) Accepted connection {{182,187,194,83},11523} -> {{100,77,176,105},5222}

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-07-21 20:35:11 ===
I(<0.430.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.3746>) Accepted connection {{182,187,194,83},11538} -> {{100,77,176,105},5222}

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-07-21 21:16:55 ===
I(<0.430.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.3748>) Accepted connection {{182,187,194,83},12779} -> {{100,77,176,105},5222}
```

Please help me out I am stuck in this for Last three days or so.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Connection` instance automatically disposed just after leaving `button1_Click` block. Move `conn` declaration into class variable and it should work

Comment: I moved  Connection conn = new Connection(); to main Form Class but it still didnt work @vitalyster

Answer (score 0):

Please attach the Xml logs when there is any.
Here you can see how to get the XMl log with MatriX:
http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/matrix-developer-tutorial/#logging